# Remove div if it has BR and no text jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where some `div` has content and some are having only `BR` tag, I am trying to remove the `div` that div has only BR tag, following is the html format

Some are like this

```
<div>
  <br>
</div>
```

And Some are like this

```
<div>
  <br>
  Text goes here text goes here..Text goes here text goes here.. Text goes here text goes here..
</div>
```

As I know I can find the blank div and remove it easily but hard to check the inner `BR` tag and remove, can somebody please help!

I tried to check blank div like this

```
if(
    $('div').is(':empty')) { 
        $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: have you tried .html() for that div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:empty` selector will not work as the `div` has `br` element.

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get all `div` element which has no `text()` then `remove()` can be used.

```js
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim().length == 0;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br>Text goes here text goes here..Text goes here text goes here.. Text goes here text goes here..
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Took me a minute to work out why this works - the key is `.text()` does not include the `<br/>` because it's a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery.filter` and test the `textContent` of `element`!

```js
$('div').filter(function() {
  return this.textContent.trim() === '';
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>Text goes here text goes here..Text goes here text goes here.. Text goes here text goes here..
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("div").text().trim()`

Example Snippet:

```js
if ($("div").text().trim() === "") {
  $("div").html("hellk")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure-JS solution: find all `BR` elements that are the only children of their parent `DIV`s and then iterate over the resulting collection and remove parent element of each `BR` element if the parent doesn’t contain non-whitespace text:

```
var brElements = document.querySelectorAll('DIV > BR:first-child:last-child');

Array.from(brElements).forEach(function(br) {
    var div = br.parentNode;

    if (0 === div.textContent.trim().length) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
});

// For older browsers not supporting `Array.from(arrayLike)`,
// use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike, 0)`.
```

This is also potentially faster than filtering all `DIV` elements in the document.

Comment: It might be faster, but it's also going to remove every `<div>` element that contains a `<br />` element regardless of text being present, since the `<br />` in the following `<div>some random text<br />and more text.</div>` would also match the `div > br:first-child:last-child` rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).text.trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
})
```